# showing a string's characters like running typing manner

Tags: javascript, marquee

actually I want know the concept behind this problem.I want to select a string's characters one by one and want to show them one by one like running typing manner by using Java script.
see what I exactly want to say http://www.yupptv.com/Movies/Movies.aspx

in this page see the Latest news below the menu bar.

see in this image http://www.sendspace.com/file/wftvr3

what should be the concept behind this and what functions should I use?

thank you.

Comment: It's called a _marquee_. There are many widgets for it.

Comment: Put your image inside the question.

Comment: [Google Search Result](https://www.google.com.bd/search?q=javascript+typing+effect&rlz=1C1KMZB_enBD539BD539&oq=javascript+typeing&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.14309j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: I can't add the image here,it require 10 reputations to add an image.

Comment: Oh sorry :/ And I can't help you, I've already upvoted your question.

Comment: Well thanx for your valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very basic one (plain text only) :

```
var s = 'This is a demo on how to build a marquee.',
    i = 0;
setTimeout(function () {
    document.body.innerHTML += s[i++];
    i < s.length && setTimeout(arguments.callee, 50);
}, 50);
```

And a live demo : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/B2CrB/.

Here is another demo using jQuery which deals with HTML : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/HVBMv/. It was only tested with Chrome, but my goal was mainly to give you a basis to play with, and an amount of code as small as possible.

Comment: Thanx a lot. this is very helpful to me to get the idea.

Comment: Can I use setInterval() function here in place of setTimeout().are they same?

Comment: Sure you can :) I've added an example.

Comment: I've forgot to mention that these functions are not the same, `setInterval` calls the function repeatedly, unlike `setTimeout`.

Comment: I want a blinking  _ (underscore) after the last letter. I have put. +"_" after innerHTML syntax. But it shows the underscore after every letter. Plz tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

As a reply to your comment, here is an alternative using `setInterval` :

```
var s = 'This is a demo on how to build a marquee.',
    i = 0,
    id;
id = setInterval(function () {
    document.body.innerHTML += s[i];
    ++i === s.length && clearInterval(id);
}, 50);
```

About javascript timers : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Timers.

---

With a blinking underscore :

```html
<span></span><span>_</span>
```

```js
var s = 'This is a demo on how to build a marquee.',
    spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span'),
    text = spans[0],
    dash = spans[1],
    i = 0,
    id;

id = setInterval(function () {
    text.innerText += s[i];
    if (++i === s.length) {
        clearInterval(id);
        dash.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        setInterval(function () {
            dash.style.visibility = (
                dash.style.visibility === 'visible' ? 'hidden' : 'visible'
            );
        }, 700);
    }
}, 50);
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/5LDs3/.