# Need Help In Javascript Text Typer Effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a javascript text typer code:

CSS:

```
body 
{
    background-color:black;
}

#writer
{ 
    font-family:Courier;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#24FF00;
    background-color:black;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var text = "Help Please, i want help.";
var counter = 0;
var speed = 25;

function type()
{
    lastText =  document.getElementById("writer").innerHTML;
    lastText+=text.charAt(counter);
    counter++;
    document.getElementById("writer").innerHTML = lastText;
}

setInterval(function(){type()},speed);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="writer"></div>
```

I want to know how can i use `<br>` tag (skipping a line or moving to another line). I tried many ways but failed, I want that if I Typed My name is Master M1nd. and then i want to go on the other line how would i go?

Comment: What happens if you just put `<br/>` in the text?

Comment: @putvande it types it as it is :|

Comment: A little auto-promotion : http://stackoverflow.com/a/20160150/1636522 :) The [second link](http://jsfiddle.net/wared/HVBMv/) might help you.

Comment: @wared Thanks for this :D, Does this works in all browser or just chrome :D ?

Comment: @user3092762 As mentionned, I've tested with Chrome only :'(

Comment: @wared Well Np, i will test with other Browsers :D One more question can you tell how can i use this All Jquery - JS  in HTML page,
For example, I am using Notepad this time, I know how to use JS by butting <script type = "text/javascript"> 
But i don't know how can i put Jquery and where jquery ends in the code, please tell... actually m new  in JS and don't even know a single code about jquery :|
You can paste the whole code, without separating in Answer :D

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you want... I'll give it a try though, give me a few minutes :)

Comment: @wared hmmm I just want that How can i use jquery in it and where jquery ends,and Js begin :)

Comment: @user3092762 jQuery is written in javascript, javascript is a language, jQuery is a library.

Comment: @wared So, How should i use it in NOTEPAD... I think I have to make a separate jQuery file, ? Right? Then Where and how will i link it in my file

Comment: I guess you know how to do a copy-paste, so, put the code between `<body>` and `</body>`, or in a separate file using Notepad if you like...

Comment: @user3092762 Updated : http://stackoverflow.com/a/20722172/1636522.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a jQuery plugin, hope this will make things easier for you. Here is a live demo : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/V7Tv6/. As you can see, jQuery is loaded thanks to the first `<script>` tag. You can then do the same for the other `<script>` tags if you like, this is not necessary but considered as a good practice. Just put the code inside each tag into separate files, then set appropriate `src` attributes in the following order :

```
<script src=".../jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src=".../jquery.marquee.js"></script>
<script src=".../init.js"></script>
```

⚠ Only tested with Chrome ⚠

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery.fn.marquee = function ($) {

    function findTextNodes(node) {
        var result = [],
            i = 0,
            child;
        while (child = node.childNodes[i++]) {
            if (child.nodeType === 3) {
                result.push(child);
            } else {
                result = result.concat(
                    findTextNodes(child)
                );
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    function write(node, text, fn) {
        var i = 0;
        setTimeout(function () {
            node.nodeValue += text[i++];
            if (i < text.length) {
                setTimeout(arguments.callee, 50);
            } else {
                fn();
            }
        }, 50);
    }

    return function (html) {
        var fragment, textNodes, text;
        fragment = $('<div>' + html + '</div>');
        textNodes = findTextNodes(fragment[0]);
        text = $.map(textNodes, function (node) {
            var text = node.nodeValue;
            node.nodeValue = '';
            return text;
        });
        this.each(function () {
            var clone = fragment.clone(),
                textNodes = findTextNodes(clone[0]),
                i = 0;
            $(this).append(clone.contents());
            (function next(node) {
                if (node = textNodes[i]) {
                    write(node, text[i++], next);
                }
            })();
        });
        return this;
    };
}(jQuery);
</script>
<script>
jQuery(function init($) {

    var html = 'A <i>marquee</i> which handles <u><b>HTML</b></u>,<br/> only tested with Chrome. <a href="#">Replay</a>';
    $('p').marquee(html);

    $('a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('p').empty();
        $('a').off('click');
        init($);
    });
});

</script>
<p></p>
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing `<br>` char by char, you can put a `\n` and transform it to `<br>` when you modify the `innerHTML`.

For example (http://jsfiddle.net/qZ4u9/1/):

```
  function escape(c) {
      return (c === '\n') ? '<br>':c;
  }

  function writer(text, out) {
      var current = 0;
      return function () {
          if (current < text.length) {
              out.innerHTML += escape(text.charAt(current++));   
          }
          return current < text.length;
      };
  }

  var typeNext = writer('Hello\nWorld!', document.getElementById('writer'));

  function type() {
        if (typeNext()) setInterval(type, 500); 
  }

  setInterval(type, 500);
```

Also probably you'll be interested in exploring requestAnimationFrame (http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/), for your typing animation :)

Comment: But it's not working smoothly as the code i have provided is working, i tried by changing 500 to other values but,
CHeck my code save it in note pad and try it.